# How to determine whether battery is low intially?

Tags: android, power-management, batterylevel, powermanager

I registered to receive `ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` and `ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY` in an activity and change some behavior according to this.

But I want to know the initial state, when the activity starts. Currently I do it with the following code:

```
Intent intent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 100);
int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 100);
boolean batteryLow = 
    (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING 
           || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING)
    && level * 100 / scale < 15;
```

This code is both too verbose and maybe different from what android thinks is low. For example, emulator does not report `status==discharging`, when I issue "power ac off" command to the telnet. I have to issue "power status discharging" as well. Not sure about real device.

Is there any other way?

Comment: I thought of having global broadcast receiver, that will modify static variable, that I can read anywhere. But the problem remains after application start.

Answer (score -1):

Thats as verbose as i can make this

```
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

return BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING && level / (float)scale < 15;
```

Comment: i have returned you the favor with a downvote...which this deserves

Answer (score -1):

As I have found out, the code in the question is the simplest possible one. The warning is shown at 15% battery level, and this value is not available through public API. There is also another level of 10%, when the screen dims. These values are defined during build time, maybe some manufacturers or android versions change it.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11970715/952135).

Comment: Are you kidding me Oliv? Those are the links from my answer.... is that how YOU found that out? Unbelievable.

Comment: You're right, but your answer is still not correct, I will comment there. I wanted to write a concise and correct answer.

Comment: Oh that's right, lets take all the information from others and write your own "correct precise" answer to look better. This is unacceptable behaviour.